# IPSec Tunnel to Amazon EC2 - Netkey, NAT, and routing issue

Tags: vpn, iptables, amazon-ec2, nat, ipsec

I'm working on getting an IPSec VPN working between Amazon EC2 and my on-premise.  The goal is to be able to safely administer stuff, up/download data, etc. over that tunnel.

I have gotten the tunnel up in openswan between a Fedora 12 instance with an elastic IP and a Cisco router that's also NATted.  I think the ipsec part is OK, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to route traffic that way; there's no "ipsec0" virutal interface because on Amazon you have to use netkey and not KLIPS for the vpn.  I hear iptables may be required and I'm an iptables noob.

On the left (Amazon), I have a 10. network.
Box 1 is  privately 10.254.110.A, publically IP 184.73.168.B.
Netkey tunnel is up.
Box 2 is publically 130.164.26.C, privately 130.164.0.D

And my .conf is:

```
conn ni
        type=           tunnel
        authby=         secret
        left=           10.254.110.A
        leftid=         184.73.168.B
        leftnexthop=    %defaultroute
        leftsubnet=     10.254.0.0/32
        right=          130.164.26.C
        rightid=        130.164.0.D
        rightnexthop=   %defaultroute
        rightsubnet=    130.164.0.0/18
        keyexchange=    ike
        pfs=            no
        auto=           start
        keyingtries=    3
        disablearrivalcheck=no
        ikelifetime=    240m
        auth=           esp
        compress=       no
        keylife=        60m
        forceencaps=    yes
        esp=            3des-md5
```

I added a route to box 1 (130.164.0.0/18 via 10.254.110.A dev eth0) but that doesn't do it for predictable reasons, when I traceroute the traffic's still going "around" and not through the vpn.

Routing table:

```
10.254.110.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.254.110.A
130.164.0.0/18 via 10.254.110.178 dev eth0  src 10.254.110.A
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
```

Anyone know how to do the routing with a netkey ipsec tunnel where both sides are NATted?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know about [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/), right?

I spent weeks working on a scheme of OpenVPN and fancy routing to accomplish the same thing, after which Amazon released this service and obsoleted my work.

Comment: Well, we need our systems to be accessible from the public Internet as well.  Amazon VPC is "either or" - if you have VPN, then you can't serve stuff to the Web.

Comment: Now that Amazon has made VPC able to connect to the public Internet as well, this answer is correct!  Just took time. :-)

Answer (score -2):

May I suggest you have a look at [vCider](http://www.vcicer.com)? It allows you to create secure, virtual networks even across provider boundaries (in case you want to expand beyond EC2). You can create your own provider-independent VPC. It also offers you to 'cloak' your cloud network: Basically, you can make your cloud nodes disappear from the public network, but you can specify exceptions for individual nodes. It offers specific features to connect your enterprise network to the cloud portion of the network.

Disclaimer: I work for vCider. But please don't let this stop you from having a look at it. You can create virtual private networks for up to 8 hosts for free.

Comment: Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion). If you are only here to promote your product then you're in the wrong place.